# How can I include bibliography into numbering?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, numbering, chapters, mwcls

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
...
\chapter{First chapter}
...
\chapter{Another chapter}
...
\begin{thebibliography}{999}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

I have in ToC:

```
1. First chapter ....... 1  
2. Another chapter ..... 1  
Bibliography ........... 1
```

I need:

```
1. First chapter ....... 1  
2. Another chapter ..... 1  
3. Bibliography ........ 1
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{*}{}{}{}
```

In this way the call `\chapter*{\bibname}` becomes `\chapter{\bibname}`, because we are telling to change the `*` into nothing.