# Section numbering in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, numbering

I'm using the biblatex package for references:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It works well except for that the references section is not numbered. So this is the same question as [How can I include bibliography into numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23012/how-can-i-include-bibliography-into-numbering) but for the biblatex package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `[heading=bibnumbered]` to  your `\printbibliography` command.

Comment: And now i feel stupid...

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Well the `biblatex` manual is much more of a reference document than a user's guide of 'how to', so you kind of have to know your way around it.